# Is there a smart contract that rewards someone who has held a token for a certain amount of time with additional tokens?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, contract-design, tokens

Basically if someone holds a token for a given time "x" amount then they are rewarded extra tokens? Is there a smart contract that can do this or is it even possible? Thank you.

Comment: Look up "staking contract". A lot of projects have this concept (a LOT).

Answer (score 0):

Like the masterchef contract you mean? Or you want the user to stake tokens for a specified amount of time so that he cant withdraw them before that time has passed? And yeah this is perfectly feasible anyways.